# When I click my JButton, the JLabel doesn't show on the window,

Tags: java, swing, jbutton

I tried to make a `JButton` that would put a `JLabel` in the window, but when I click the button, it doesn't seem to put the `JLabel` in the window. The button seems to work when I use it for the console, but not for putting the `JLabel` in the window. Why is this, and what should I do?

Here's my code:

```
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.GridLayout;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;

import javax.swing.BorderFactory;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JPanel;

public class AnimaleseTranslator implements ActionListener {
    
    private static JPanel panel;
    private static JLabel label;
    
    public AnimaleseTranslator() {
        
        JFrame frame = new JFrame();
        
        panel = new JPanel();
        panel.setBorder(BorderFactory.createEmptyBorder(220, 391, 220, 391));
        panel.setLayout(new GridLayout(0, 1));
        
        frame.add(panel, BorderLayout.CENTER);
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.pack();
        frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null); // centers the JFrame
        frame.setTitle("Animalese Translator");
        frame.setVisible(true);
        
        JButton button = new JButton("Click me!");
        button.setBounds(100, 100, 98, 55);
        button.addActionListener(this);
        panel.add(button);
        
        label = new JLabel("lkdsajflksdjlaskdjf");
        label.setBounds(200, 200, 50, 50);
        
    }
    
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new AnimaleseTranslator();
    }

    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        panel.add(label);
    }

}
```

Comment: Do ***not*** use `setBounds(...)`. It doesn't work with layout managers, and even when it does work (with null layouts), the GUI's so created don't work well and are beasts to maintain. Just don't do it. Instead, add your label on GUI creation using the layout managers as they are built to be used, and then swap image icons in the label as needed. or change the label's text as needed.

Comment: Remember to always [revalidate](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/13/docs/api/java.desktop/java/awt/Component.html#revalidate()) and [repaint](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/13/docs/api/java.desktop/java/awt/Component.html#repaint()) whenever you'd like the layout manager to update.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> but when I click the button, it doesn't seem to put the JLabel in the window.

1. The setBounds(...) statement does nothing. Swing uses layout managers by default and the layout manager will set the size/location of each component. So get rid of the setBounds() statement because it is confusing.
2. Components need to be added to the frame BEFORE the frame is made visible. The pack() or setVisible() statement will then invoke the layout manager.
3. After you add a component to panel on a visible frame you need to invoke `panel.revalidate()` to invoke the layout manager. So you need to add the `revalidate()` in the ActionListener.
4. Get rid of the `setBorder(...)` statement until you better understand what it does. The problem with your current code is the border is too big, so there is no room for the button and label to display properly.

Comment: One trick I've found when working with labels which are initially invisible is to set them up with a transparent icon of the size they will later use. If it's text, put the longest string expected into the label, pack the GUI then `setText("")` to make them invisible again. Doing these things helps the GUI become the size it *needs* to be.

Comment: I got a comment on my question saying that I have to repaint AND revalidate. Do I have to repaint? But thanks for this answer.

Comment: Most of the time the revalidate() is all you need. Sometimes people add the repaint().